# Is there a relationship between a java package name and the dependency to code in build.gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, micronaut

I need annotation

```
@MicronautTest
```

which resides in package

```
io.micronaut.test.annotation
```

But I don't know how the corresponding dependency line in build.gradle looks like.

Is there a chance to determine the correct entry from the package name or the respective maven repository?

Comment: Please don't put your name or tagline at the end of questions. See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the test runner you use. For running tests with Spock for example you can use

```
testCompile "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock:1.1.3
```

You can find further readings at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a relationship between a java package name and the dependency
>   to code in build.gradle?

No.  The Java package name is separate from anything that would show up in a dependency declaration.

> Is there a chance to determine the correct entry from the package name
>   or the respective maven repository?

There is not.  There is no relationship between their names.